# Nuget install claims packages already installed

Tags: nuget

I'm running the following command on a build server:
Nuget.exe install MyPkgName -Source C:\temp\somefolder -OutputDirectory C:\temp\someotherfolder

I'm running it as part of unpacking build artifacts (nuget packages) in TeamCity as part of a packaging process on a build server. So the same packages have been unpacked before on this server, but the workspace is cleaned everytime, yet it fails with:
*All packages listed in C:\temp\packages.config are already installed.*

There is no packages.config in that location, and I can't understand where nuget is storing the information that the package is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Was a regex issue in the powershell script where it didnt get the package name correctly, my bad.